# Convert string to date and time using Momentjs

Tags: javascript, string, meteor, type-conversion, momentjs

How to format this string to date and time using Momentjs?

```
01/08/2018 12:00 AM.
```

I am thinking that it has to be converted to GMT for the time to work. Though I have seen many cases on SO but many of them only extracted the date leaving the time.

Comment: What did you tried? Which is your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an extremely simple task with MomentJS. Try this one:

```
let x = moment("01/08/2018 12:00 AM").format('DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A');
alert(x);
```

Example in JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5kf6afme